# How to take id in table ci_sessions (codeigniter 3)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My script login is like this :

```
public function validate_login()
{
   ...
   echo '<pre>';print_r($this->session->all_userdata());die();
   ...
}
```

The result of print_r :

```
<pre>Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1465192054
)
```

In table ci_sessions, update record like this :

[image]

I want to take id(737d1bd741c9c06ceda3a3a45c1009fc5fafd44a) in table ci_sessions. but i'm still confused.

How to take id in table ci_sessions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter 3 there is a function called `session_id()` by which you may get the session ID.

For more details

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata

Moreover you can still access `$this->session->session_id` to get session ID

Comment: I using : `$this->session->session_id`. It's working. Thank you very much

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189488/how-to-remove-single-quotes-in-prepare-statement